# How do I create a circuit based on this truth table? The solution I implemented is not working as expected

Tags: angular, hardware, circuit-diagram

I am trying to create a circuit based on this truth table below:
can you describe how to make the circuit using only logic gates

```
In_1 In_2 In_3  Out
 0    0    0     0
 0    0    1     1
 0    1    0     1
 0    1    1     1
 1    0    0     1
 1    0    1     1
 1    1    0     1
 1    1    1     1
```

This is what I have done so far
[image: my work]

However, this circuit is not working as expected. It is giving me this error:
[image: error]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how do I fix this? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

A circuit based on that truth table would just be a simple OR gate, the AND gate is redundant in your circuit. This might also fix the error you're getting.

Comment: yes sorry my bad I was overthinking the situation. didn't expect the solution to be that simple.